# BIOS not saving SATA RST -> AHCI mode change (but saving other changes properly)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bios, sata

Title. Trying to dual-boot windows & linux on the same laptop. Found that linux installer can't see hard drives while SATA is in RST mode, so I tried to change it to AHCI - BIOS just does not save it, but it properly saves other settings, like secure boot etc. Every time I changed RST to AHCI on the next startup it was RST again, no matter what. Laptop is Lenovo Yoga C940.

Comment: Upadte UEFI and try again. That said, this question, so far, has nothing to do with Ubuntu, only tangentially because Intel RST is incompatible.

Comment: @ChanganAuto already updated to last version :(